# Peewee генерирует верный запрос, но обращаясь к БД ничего не возвращает, хотя если вставить этот запрос в MySQL WB все работает

Tags: python, mysql, sql, peewee

Запрос, который я пытаюсь сделать в python:

```
data = PlayerGroupTime \
        .select(PlayerGroupTime.player_id, fn.SUM(PlayerGroupTime.time)) \
        .group_by(PlayerGroupTime.player_id) \
        .order_by(fn.SUM(PlayerGroupTime.time).desc()) \
        .limit(10)
```

Далее, само собой **peewee** генерирует запрос, который выглядит так:

```
SELECT 
   `t1`.`player_id`, SUM(`t1`.`time`) 
FROM 
   `player_group_time` AS `t1` 
WHERE 
   (`t1`.`time` != 0) 
GROUP BY `t1`.`player_id` 
ORDER BY SUM(`t1`.`time`) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Но вместо того, чтобы вывести нужную информацию, выводится **None**, при этом в **MySQL Workbench**, подставляя генерируемый запрос, выводится все что нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что выводит `print(list(data))`?

Comment: [<PlayerGroupTime: None>, <PlayerGroupTime: None>, ... <PlayerGroupTime: None>]

Comment: Я что-то не вижу метода `get()` ... или перебора `for row in data:`

Comment: Через `get()` же не получится сгенерировать SQL запрос SELECT. А `for row in data` как раз и выводит 10 раз `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После дебага кода, я увидел, что у все нужные значения у меня возвращается. Переменная `row`, если прокрутить через цикл `for row in data`, содержит нужные значения, а хапрос нужно немного переписать, чтобы нормально обратиться к значениям суммы:

```
data = PlayerGroupTime \
    .select(PlayerGroupTime.player_id, fn.SUM(PlayerGroupTime.time).alias('sum_time')) \
    .group_by(PlayerGroupTime.player_id) \
    .order_by(fn.SUM(PlayerGroupTime.time).desc()) \
    .limit(10)

for row in data:
    print(row.sum_time)
```

`print(row.sum_time)` - выведит нам нужные значения суммы времени.